# Rsyslog not forwarding when running as service

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate, logstash

I have 2 local VM's running CentOS 7 to simulate our production environment. 1 proxy server and 1 centralized (ELK) server. On the ELK server is running logstash to collect al syslogs from running instances.
The proxy server is provisioned with Rsyslog (and logrotate) via Ansible. Install syslog and logrotate. Copy configuration. Restart service. Really basic configuration, just a `*.* @@IP.ADD.RE.SS:12345` in a `10-logstash.conf` located in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` and the rest is standard.
But, it doesn't seem to send logs to logstash. When I tail `/var/log/messages` i see output from the proxy container running on the instance. But none is forwarded to the logging server.

So I googled and found the DebuggingOnDemand option. When i stop the rsyslogd service and manually run `sudo rsyslog -n` it starts forwarding logs. When i run `rsyslog -d` (without sudo) I get notified it can't write the .pid file.
So my guess is, when it is ran as a service it does not have sufficient rights to work properly?
I cant manually start rsyslog without sudo. But i can start rsyslog as a service (`sudo service rsyslog start`) and confirmed that it is running.

So where is exactly the problem? Is it the process itself? Is it not able to read the log files? I couldn't imagine my configuration is wrong, as rsyslog is forwarding correctly when run manually.
I dont know what logging or output to provide, so if any is needed please ask and i will try to provide.

`rsyslogd -N 10` output (with another configuration file which is confirmed working in production, same forwarder but a bit more options defined)

```
rsyslogd: version 7.4.7, config validation run (level 10), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: module 'imuxsock' already in this config, cannot be added [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
rsyslogd: $WorkDirectory: /rsyslog/work can not be accessed, probably does not exist - directive ignored [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2181 ]
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rsyslog.conf and other config files if you have any?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, this is related to SELinux, but because disabling SELinux is not the best choice I corrected the problem whit this:

```
sudo semanage port -d -t unreserved_port_t -p tcp 9092
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9092
```

And then restart syslogd.
You can see SELinux alerts with this command:

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Comment: To be honest i have no way of verifying this anymore as this was 3 years ago. If someone else can verify this, please comment so i can mark this question as answered! Thanks Ali for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I had this same issue. Based on what was posted I had a hard time figuring out what to do.

For me the problem was solved by running this command:

```
semanage port -m -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 443
```

After that I just had to bounce the rsyslog service:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

I also found an article that does a good job handling other cases where selinux may block the syslog/rsyslog service

https://support.logz.io/hc/en-us/articles/209486429-Troubleshooting-Rsyslog-SELinux-configuration

Hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score -1):

Found solution for this disabling SELinux on the rsyslog (forwarder) host. Ideally a more fine-grained configuration would work too.